# Build a web service so that a Winform client can send values to a SQL Server database through POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, post, asmx

I am attempting to build a web service to send data to a local SQL Server database that I have on ASP.NET using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. The problem is that I have never built a web service before and do not know how to do this.

I have managed to create a blank .asmx page, but do not know how to implement the Post method to send data to my "Research" database. I have looked online but haven't found any clear-cut examples or tutorials. Please and thank you in advance.

Below is the blank .asmx page

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="WebService" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, 
uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService  : System.Web.Services.WebService {

 [WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

var db = Database.Open("Research");

[WebMethod]
public void Post(Research Name)
{

}

}
```

Comment: If you're building a brand new web service, you likely should be using ASP.NET Core, and doing a Web API Controller within that. Don't use ASMX. It's ancient dead technology.

Comment: First google result: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-tutorials

Comment: I completely agree with @mason - you should create a REST API with ASP.NET Core, given that your using VS2017

Comment: Use web api 2 for REST. That is the best for web service.

Comment: I was already working on a website application which had graphs that are supposed to read the data from the SQL Server database. Would i have to start all over from scratch or is there a way to reference the web API project to the  website project so that the graphs i have can read the data from the database in the second project?